# checkbox checked when value same with data from database-javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

hi everyone please help,
i'm new in javascript, i have checkbox with random value, so i want to when there is data from database same with value in checkbox, checkbox will checked,

this is my checkbox,

```
@foreach ($loin as $loin)
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input class="custom-control-input loincode" type="checkbox" id="{{$loin->sap_code}}" name="sap_code[]" 
       value="{{$loin->sap_code}}">
     <label for="{{$loin->sap_code}}" class="custom-control-label">{{$loin->sap_code}} 
     </label>
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

and this my js

```
$('.tampilModalUbahPts').on('click',function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.modal-body form').attr('action','/pts/'+id+'/update');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ptspt/getubah',
        data: {id : id},
        method:'get',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#lbs').val(data.lbs);
            $('.loincode').attr("checked",data.loin== value);
        }
    });
});
```

sorry for bad english.

Comment: What is data.loin? what is its type? Can u check `console.log(data.loin);`  and `console.log(typeof data.loin);`

Comment: data.loin is array,,this data.loin example  ["108591"]

Comment: I added answer u can use   for checkbox only true or false as type. So you can use code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then use this

```
$('.loincode').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr("checked",(data.loin && data.loin.filter(x=>(x==$(this).val())).length) ? true : false);
});
```

```js
var data={loin:["108591","108592"]}


$('.loincode').each(function( index ) {
     $(this).attr("checked",(data.loin && data.loin.filter(x=>(x==$(this).val())).length) ? true : false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  class="loincode" value="108591" />
<input type="checkbox"  class="loincode" value="108592" />
<input type="checkbox"  class="loincode" value="108593" />
```

Comment: hi appreaciate for your answer, but i have same lenght for the value.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed your criteria part I updated answer now

Comment: diffrent value, in checkbox i have 3 options, 108591,108592 and 108593. and from db the value is 108591, i want if the value from database same with checbox, example 108591, chexbox in 108591 will checked, and 108592 and 108593 not checked.

Comment: Are you sure that values are correct in your checkboxes. I put jsfiddle for your example u can check it answer it works

Comment: ah sorry i miss a character, its working, but when i have 2 value in database example ["108591","108592"], the chechbox only checked on 108591